# HTML5 Canvas y-height not correct

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, canvas

So I'm just trying to make a simple animated HMTL canvas with an animated block that moves around the canvas using WASD. I initially noticed that painting a rectangle on the canvas of size 5,5 made what looked like a rectangle of size 5,10. When testing my redrawing function and printing to the console the x and y location of the element in the canvas, I noticed that my rectangle can go from 1-300 in the X direction, but only 1-150 in the Y direction. This happens even though the canvas is styled as 300,300. Can anyone figure out if I've done something silly?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-holder holder" id="instruction-holder">
        <p class="text" id="instruction">Use WASD to navigate around the viewer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="holder" id="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
    #canvas {
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.holder {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the js

```
var UP = "87", DOWN = "83", LEFT = "65", RIGHT = "68", X = 10, Y = 5, XSIZE = 10, YSIZE = 5;
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var xPos, yPos;

window.addEventListener("load",init);
document.addEventListener('keydown',move);

function init() {
    xPos = 1;
    yPos = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,XSIZE,YSIZE);
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
}

function reDraw(delX, delY) {
    console.log(yPos+delY + " " + (xPos+delX));
    if (xPos+delX > 0 && xPos+delX < 300 && 
        yPos+delY > 0 && yPos+delY < 150) {
        clear();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        xPos = xPos+delX;
        yPos = yPos+delY;
        ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,XSIZE,YSIZE);
    }
}

function move(ev) {
    var delX, delY;
    var key = ev.keyCode;
    if (key == UP) {
        delX = 0;
        delY = -Y;
    } else if (key == DOWN) {
        delX = 0;
        delY = Y;
    } else if (key == LEFT) {
        delX = -X;
        delY = 0;       
    } else if (key == RIGHT) {
        delX = X;
        delY = 0;
    }

    if (delX != undefined && delY != undefined) {
        reDraw(delX, delY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the size of canvas explicitly or it will use the default size of 300x150 (CSS only scales the element, not the bitmap - the bitmap of 300x150 is stretched to fit what you see on screen by the CSS rule, but the bitmap will remain the same size internally):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Then just remove these:

```
#canvas {
  /* width: 300px; */
  /* height:300px; */
  ...
```